# Which serverless database to store user data and images?

Tags: sql-server, mysql, blob, azure-blob-storage

I am designing a cloud deployed system where users can log in and upload some user-specific images (not super large files, but maybe sometimes >1mb that are then later displayed in the system to the specific user. I am asking myself if I really need Blob storage or if I can go with a SQL database only... what do you think?

Thank you very much.

Comment: How important are the images?

Comment: Welcome to the site, Manfred!  There's a really detailed discussion in the linked duplicate about the pros and cons of storing binary files inside or outside the database.  If that doesn't cover your question, plus update to indicate what else you're looking for and it can be reopened.

Comment: Hi, thanks you Josh, my system is serverless, so it is quite different then the other article I think. Can you reopen it?

Answer (score 0):

You could certainly meet your requirements with SQL Server if you use Filestream or FileTable.

to quote from the linked article :-
The goals of the FileTable feature include the following:

Windows API compatibility for file data stored within a SQL Server database. Windows API compatibility includes the following:

Non-transactional streaming access and in-place updates to FILESTREAM data.

A hierarchical namespace of directories and files.

Storage of file attributes, such as created date and modified date.

Support for Windows file and directory management APIs.

Compatibility with other SQL Server features including management tools, services, and relational query capabilities over FILESTREAM and file attribute data.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/blob/filetables-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15

Answer (score 0):

Put images separately; reference them via `<img ...>` in HTML.  Period, end of discussion.

(If it is not HTML, then perhaps this is not the 'right' answer.)